# Why doesn't the || operator work for me?

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

I'm new to coding and I'm currently working on my first project alone. I'm trying to make the program compare some data but for some reason I can't use the OR (||) operator. Anybody know why? It's a WPF project. 
Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: rndNumber == x || rnbNumber==y

Comment: Read the error message?  Your used to JavaScript I'd bet. Hint: You need a bool involved...

Comment: Are you checking if `las2` is null or are you checking if `rndNumb` is equal to either `las1` or `las2`?

Comment: Please post your code right in the answer (in text format).

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it should be

```
while (rndNumber == 1as1 || rndNumber == 1as2)
```

After `||` operator you need to specify full boolean expresion, there is not shorthand for right argument only.

Comment: This should be `while`, not `if`.

Comment: Good catch, changed. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like so:

```
while (rndNumb == las1 || rndNumb == las2)
```

In your approach, only the first equation "rndNumb == las1" works as you expect. The second "las2" is only a variable. So you are comparing a boolean "true/false" to an int variable.

Comment: An answer would help people much more if it would provide an explanation of why this was wrong in the first place...

Comment: @MongZhu Here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Make your code like this:

```
    while ((rndNumb == las1) || (rndNumb == las2))
```

Imagine it like this: you ask the computer to run the loop only when one of the conditionals occur, and so you need to make it clear what are the conditionals:

either (rndNumb=las1) || (rndNumb=las2), and so, you put it in the brackets.

Comment: The brackets are not necessary

Comment: I put the brackets **not** because its specifically necessary but to make the conditional more readable (which, in production environments is a must).

Comment: I agree that with brackets it is easier to see how this solves the problem in the question. But I thought you meant the brackets are mandatory. My personal opinion is that it reads better without the brackets, because they add more clutter.